# Add Hours to Date/Time, Exclude Weekends

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a date/time in 24 hour format in C4: `10/27/16 1:00`

I have a time interval in D15: `1:00 (=1/24)`

I want to be able to add this time interval to start time C4, and display the result in C5. Then add the time interval to C5, and display in C6, etc etc, with each cell adding the time interval to the date/time.

However, I want it to exclude Saturdays and Sundays.

There are a lot of code samples out there, but some either seem overly complicated for what I need, or don't work right for me. I really prefer a formula, not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula, paste it in C5 and drag it as per your needs,

`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(C4+$D$15)=1,WEEKDAY(C4+$D$15)=7),IF(WEEKDAY(C4+$D$15)=1,C4+DAY(1)+$D$15,C4+DAY(2)+$D$15),C4+$D$15)`

This formula finds the day of the week. If its a sunday or a saturday, it ignores the days, if not adds up the interval. Hope this helps.